# Different web element position in different resolution

Tags: html, css

Image 1 1920X1080:

[image]

Image 2 1400X1050:

[image]

As you can see from image 1 i design it at resolution 1920X1080 and it look awesome, but when I open it at resolution 1400X1050 it looks so horrible as like in pict 2. Can anyone suggest me the best solution for this case?

Heres my background CSS:

```
body {

background-image: url(images/background-photo.jpg);


background-position: center center;


background-repeat: no-repeat;


background-attachment: fixed;


background-size: 100% auto;


background-color:#245528;



}

 /* For mobile devices */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
body {

background-image: url(images/background-photo-mobile-devices.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you using any CSS framework? You may want to look into it and its fluid/responsive design tags.

Comment: Please post codes here

Comment: @Varun Done, I already update it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to keep the aspect ratio of the background image, is it? If so, how do you want to have your background image when the image is stretched, do you want to have some blank area on the top/left and bottom/right?

Comment: @Simon yeah i want to leave a blank area to make this page fit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show images in good way in different resolutions then you need to have different images for different resolutions. You can implement it by using srcset:

```
<img src="small.jpg" srcset="medium.jpg 1000w, large.jpg 2000w" alt="yah">
```

Source: [Responsive Images: If you’re just changing resolutions](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the right style for your case is

```
background-size: contain;
```

instead of

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

the `contain` will always keep the image shown in your container element, so when the width or height is too small for the image, it will try to resize the image, so that the entire image is shown(with possibly blank area on the top/left or bottom/right). Instead, the `100% auto` will always try to stretch the image to make it as wide as the screen.